# Redirect user to the Subscription page in the playstore

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I've been reading this website : 
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html
Because I read that "Currently, the In-app Billing API does not provide support for programatically canceling subscriptions from inside the purchasing app", I would like to redirect the user to this page to manage his own subscription.

I'm not able to find how to open the subscription page from an application.
I was thinking about opening it like a external link with :

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But I don't even know the link I need to put in... -_-

Thanks in advance for your answer! :)

Comment: Can people at least explain why they down-vote my question?
Sorry, but for me, no question are "stupid", so if it's so easy, just tell me the link to the answer or a piece of code!

Comment: This is from the official Android Developers website: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subs#deep-link

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Ok, so I haven't received a better answer (actually... no answer at all..yet).
For other that might research an answer, here is mine :

```
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                   Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

**Note:** It seems, that the `market:` syntax is deprecated and the web intent is automatically forwarded to the PlayStore app.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks for the code, it helps.

Just to add a little in the URL,

> https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions

to take you directly at the Subscriptions screen in the phone.

Answer (score 13):

At google io 2018 they announced this link

```
https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?sku=XXX&package=YYY
```

Just replace sku and package

Comment: in v6 they replaced  code "sku" with "product"  , this url also need to update ?